# Adding bluetooth to msp430

Tags: bluetooth, msp430, android

I was wondering, what is the best option to add bluetooth connectivity to a small msp430 project. I have tried to google this, and have found various resources, but I am not sure which ones to go with. I am looking for cheap and easy solutions. Ultimately I would like to control a small robot with an android phone. Thanks

Comment: Not a real answer or endorsement, but I ran across this today - http://www.dealextreme.com/p/wireless-bluetooth-rs232-ttl-transceiver-module-80711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo. Directly used and application notes on TI website how to integrate these modules and possible sample code in one of the 2 free IDE's

This is a BlueTooth 2.1 Module that can be interfaced in many ways to many other development kits. This is a cheap option for a complete module that does what it says- no messing about.

- [The landing page-also shows you where to order(requested by op)](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2560-pan1325)
- [Texas Instruments Module Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2560-pan1325.pdf)

What did you say? How about Wifi?

- [Bluetooth 2.1 + WIFI b/g/n (but it needs an antenna- not expensive- good range!)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/wl1271-tiwi.pdf)

As a buy and use it solution after weeks of research those are good. but also there are many avaialble

- [look at this](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-transceivers/3539948?k=bluecore) (but CSR dont like selling to end users.. after Apple bought a few million chips from them they seem to stuck their noses up theri a$$hsszz...

There are projects to build your own BT device - but i stronly suggest using a module as many hours of reseach went into these moduels to produce the best range and power consumption using good components.

It is a bit early - but this is a very impressive module from TI
[C2450](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540)
Why early- becasue it uses BT version 4- which only Iphone 4S use (surprissee- it used this chip- suck o n that CSR!) and the specifications of BT4 are amazing- super low power, new methods of connecting using close range authentication, lower power advertising and pairing.. runs on a coil battery for years! But we have to wait till smart phones catch up.. I have not found any Smartphone that supports BT4 yet.(aprt form iPhone4s)

other problem is-- there is no module yet- so you would have to buy the chip, make a pcb, match and tune the aeriel and hope for the best..

Best of all - its ALL IN ONE- so you can programme this chip with 8 or 12 IO's i think so it can do all sort of clever things like your MSP430 (based on the new extreme low power MSP edition) So in the sample you would need 1 crystal- 2 balancing caps, 1 decoupling cap, and you might be able to use an on-board antenna to avoid tuning issues.

Comment: this reads a bit like a 30 second TV add - but wait... there's more! :)

Comment: Act now and we'll throw in a set of Ginsu Knives!  But wait, if you call in the next 30 minutes, we'll double your order and throw in the Super Shammy and Showtime Rotisserie as your free gift.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the first link you pasted obsolete. I don't see an option to buy it.

Comment: @shiraz Defintaly not obsolete. Th TI website is a bit strange to get used to - but you will find a weath of information there. I edited the post- the first link will take you th e products page, with info where to buy, and articles how to use with MSP430. Be kind, upvote.

Comment: Yes I see the option to buy it and the status 'active' too. Last time I checked it was different. And thanks again for the help. For the upvote, I am new here and I don't have 15 pts to do that :(

Comment: @shiraz Yea i know- it seems upvotes in this forum are dealt in weight of gold. Never mind. At least i have the satisfaction that i helped you out. Dont hesitate to ask new questions and Welcome to Electronics SE!

Answer (score 1):

Cheap is inversely proportional to easy!

You can buy the RN-41 off the shelf for about $25. Give it 3.3V and it will send/receive serial data over Bluetooth. Right out the box the default settings will get you communicating. It's quite easy to use and comes with built-in chip antenna. Available at Digikey and SparkFun.

For a bit more (about double the price), Sena has some nice modules that are more rugged and have connectors for external antennas. They also have more range available IIRC.

If you go much cheaper than that, the difficulty increases.

Comment: Thanks. I see there are options to buy RN 41 with 3 or 4 options. And I can't figure out what exactly does HID , HCI and interfacing USB with HCI mean. When and why should I care about these details?

Comment: Those aren't ordering options; they're communication interfaces supported by the device. They are explained here: http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN_41 . For your application (connect to a device with a serial port), you just need SPP: Serial Port Protocol. I haven't used HID or HCI, so I don't know how hard they are to implement on the microcontroller, but obviouslly a serial port is trivial.